# Azure Application Settings - The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was

Tags: azure, model-view-controller

I am publishing a web application to azure. I want to create my connection string in the Azure portal instead of showing security information in web.config file.

I keep getting the below error message:

> The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development.  This will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not remove the line of code that throws this exception. If you wish to use Database First or Model First, then make sure that the Entity Framework connection string is included in the app.config or web.config of the start-up project. If you are creating your own DbConnection, then make sure that it is an EntityConnection and not some other type of DbConnection, and that you pass it to one of the base DbContext constructors that take a DbConnection.

The message goes away when I delete the connection string in Azure and use my web.config file as normal.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the same value in web.config as in App Setting? Trying to determine if it is the value that is the problem or where you are defining it.

Comment: Yes - When I use the connection string in web.config without any Azure application settings it is fine. Then I copy the connection string in to Azure application settings and I get the above message. My ultimate intention is to blank out the security information from the web.config.